# How to add new pages (ROR) when my page of news is full?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

How to add new pages (ROR) when my page is full? I unload my application on Heroku. But I have no database. For example, I have this page: http://priroda-site.tk/mammal/index. I add new posts every day. What define in controller, that pages automatically created? I should have 6 posts on every page.

Stucture

```
post
post
post
post
post
post

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

My post structure

**html.erb**

```
  <!-- bee -->
        <div class="post_box">
          <div class="date_box">
            <p>28 JULY 2014</p>
          </div> <!-- end of date box -->

          <div class="post_body">

            <a href="#"><%= image_tag "fakts/bee.jpg", :size=>"470x320" %></a>
            <p>
            </p>
            <br>
            <br>
          </div> <!-- end of post body -->
        </div> <!-- end of a post -->
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called **pagination.** There are a multitude of solutions for this in Rails, I tend to use [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)

Comment: but I have no database